# Can't connect to MySql with PHP JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I have the following `PHP` code that processes some form `JSON` objects posted by `AJAX`

My problem is that Nothing is being added to the MySql table. Consequently I keep getting the `referenceNumber` as null.

Any suggestions??

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (is_ajax()) {
  if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { //Checks if action value exists
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch($action) { //Switch case for value of action
      case "test": test_function(); break;
    }
  }
}

//Function to check if the request is an AJAX request
function is_ajax() {
  return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){

    $firstName  = $_POST["firstName"];
    $lastName   = $_POST['lastName'];
    $name       = $firstName. ' ' .$lastName ;
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $subject    = $_POST['subject'];
    $hear       = $_POST['hear'];
    $message    = $_POST['message'];

    date_default_timezone_set("EST");
    $date = date("Y.m.d"); // 2015.10.01
    $day = date("l"); // Sunday
    $time = date("g:ia"); // 1:25am

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "aaa", "xxx", "onlineMessages");
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $add = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`Date`, `Day`, `Time`, `Name`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Subject`, `From`, `Message`)
        VALUES ('$date','$day','$time','$name','$email','$phone','$subject','$hear','$message')");


    $get_ref_number = mysqli_query(" SELECT `Reference #` FROM `test` where Name='$name' and Phone='$phone' and Message='$message' ");
    $ref_number_fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($get_ref_number);
    $ref_number = $ref_number_fetch['Reference #'];

    // Close connection
    mysqli_close($link);

    //Returned Data
    $arr = array('Name' => $name, 'Phone' => $phone, 'referenceNumber' => $ref_number);
    echo json_encode($arr);

}
?>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var form = $('#contact-form');

      form.submit(function(){
        var data = {
          "action": "test"
        };
        data = form.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "json",
              url: form.attr('action'),
              data: data,
              success: function(data) {
                  $(".the-return").html(
                    data["Name"] + data["Phone"] + data["referenceNumber"]
                  );
                  alert("Form submitted successfully.\nReturned json: " + data["json"]);
              },
              error : function(){
                  form.html("Error!" + data["json"]);
              }
        });
        return false;
      });
});
```

Comment: is `Reference #` is your column  name??

Comment: No!, `test` is my table name

Comment: You have a `SELECT Reference #` Does that column name actually contain a `#` symbol???

Comment: Do yourself a favour, dont use odd column names like that try for example `reference_no`, its also recommended to use all lower case for column names

Comment: What DataType is your `Date` column as that could be your issue

Comment: I used to process some other data using a previous version of `PHP` file to the same table with no any problems ..

Comment: Also this looks like code written with the old `mysql_` extension that has been converted to use the newer `mysqli_` extension, without checking the required function parameters. The `mysqli_query()` function has 2 parameters [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) You code does not!!!!!

Comment: The new here in this `PHP` file is the AJAX and JSON part at the beginning of my code

Comment: I beleive that processing the data using `json` is the main reason "because this the new part" but I can't figure it out

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything. **And watch the errors flow**

Comment: Also look at the `$date = date("Y.m.d")` line. MYSQL DateTime or Date type columns require the date in the format `$date = date("Y-m-d")` or `$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Comment: thank you for your reply, but as I mentioned everything were going just fine before posting and receiving data using `JSON` ... It has to have something to do with the connection but I can't figure it out

Comment: Well try getting rid of that `is it ajax stuff` and just call your function

Comment: Or at least add a `default` to your switch which returns an error to the ajax code which you can see and tailor to tell you  something about what is or is not happening

Comment: when I get rid of the `function is_ajax() {` part It returns the AJAX `error : function(){`

Comment: would you please edit my code, I am a beginner in these ajax stuff

Comment: what you are saying is making very scenes, the reason is something in the beginning oh my `PHP` code (the `ajax` part) ... put since I don't understant what it is doing, I cant figure it out :(

Comment: I dont see the need for any of that `is it ajax` code anyway. Why do you believe any of that is necessary

Comment: because when I remove it, it fires the `error : function(){` part of my JS AJAX

Comment: and I dunno why :(

Comment: It fires the `error` function due to all the errors I have previously mentioned.

Comment: I also beleive that removeing it return the error, because it has a relation with the `var data = {"action": "test"};
  data = form.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);` part in my JS code

Comment: Yea, thats crap too, you are overwritting `data`

Comment: I think your best bet is to read some good tutorials and maybe the jQuery manual

Comment: May you please modify my code to get it to work?